# javafx trigger calculation across classes with bindings

Tags: javafx, binding, java-8

I'm a bit stuck, and maybe someone can help. I want to have a "grand total" calculated whenever certain fields are changed.

I've made a prototype in excel to illustrate:

[image: Mockup of two tables, Products and Summary]

So whenever a price or quantity is changed, the total cost is recalculated, and the summary should also be updated, including the "Final Total". I have employed bindings and they aren't working, except when the summary items are first created, and subsequently the finalTotal field won't recalculate.

I have two classes, one called Product, which contains the properties `productName`, `priceEach`, `quantity`, `productTotal`. Whenever the `priceEach` or `quantity` properties are set, a `calculateTotal()` method is called to update `productTotal`.
Here's the code:

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleFloatProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Product {
   private final StringProperty productName;
   private final FloatProperty priceEach;
   private final IntegerProperty quantity;
   private  FloatProperty productTotal;

   public Product(){
      this.productName = new SimpleStringProperty("Product Name");
      this.priceEach = new SimpleFloatProperty(0);
      this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
      this.productTotal = new SimpleFloatProperty(0);
   }

   public Product(String name, float priceEach, int quantity){
      this.productName = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
      this.priceEach = new SimpleFloatProperty(priceEach);
      this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
      this.productTotal = calculateProductTotal();
   }

   private FloatProperty calculateProductTotal() {
      return new SimpleFloatProperty(priceEach.get()*quantity.get());
   }

   public void setProductName(String name){
      productName.set(name);
   }

   public void setPriceEach(float price){
      priceEach.set(price);
      productTotal = calculateProductTotal();
   }

   public void setQuantity(int number){
      quantity.set(number);
      productTotal = calculateProductTotal();
   }

   public String getProductName(){ return productName.get(); }
   public float getPriceEach(){ return priceEach.get(); }
   public int getQuantity(){ return quantity.get(); }
   public float getProductTotal(){ return productTotal.get(); }

   public StringProperty productNameProperty() { return productName;}
   public FloatProperty priceEachProperty() { return priceEach;}
   public IntegerProperty quantityProperty() { return quantity;}
   public FloatProperty productTotalProperty() { return productTotal;}

   @Override
   public String toString(){
      return " Product: " + getProductName() +
              ", Price: " + getPriceEach() +
              ", Quantity: " + getQuantity() +
              ", Total cost: " + getProductTotal();
   }     
}
```

I also have a Summary class with two properties that bind unidirectionally to the corresponding properties in the Products class. This is where the problem is.

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Summary {
   private FloatProperty finalTotal;
   public ObservableList<Item> itemsSummary = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 

   public Summary(){
      finalTotal=new SimpleFloatProperty(0);
   }
   public Item add()
   {
      Item newItem = new Item(); 
      itemsSummary.add(newItem);
      newItem.productTotalProperty().addListener((obs, oldAmount, newAmount) -> {
            System.out.println("Item total changed from "+oldAmount+" to "+newAmount);
            calculateTotal();
            System.out.println("Final total: "+finalTotal);
         });
      return newItem;    
   } 
   
   public class Item{
      private final StringProperty productName;
      private  FloatProperty productTotal;
      
      public Item(){
         this.productName = new SimpleStringProperty("");
         this.productTotal =  new SimpleFloatProperty(-1);    
      }
      public void setProductName(String name) { productName.set(name); }
      public void setProductTotal(float total) { productTotal.set(total); }
      public String getProductName() { return productName.get(); }
      public float getProductTotal() { return productTotal.get(); }
      public StringProperty productNameProperty() { return productName;}
      public FloatProperty productTotalProperty() { return productTotal;}     
   }
   
   private void calculateTotal(){
      float runningTotal=0;
      for (Item i: itemsSummary )
         runningTotal+= i.getProductTotal();
      finalTotal.set(runningTotal);
   }
             
   @Override
   public String toString(){
      String output= "";
      for(Item i: itemsSummary){
         String pn = i.getProductName();
         float  pt = i.getProductTotal();
         output = output +"\n"+ String.format("Product: %s,  Product cost: %.2f", pn, pt); 
      }
      return output+
                "\nFinal total: " + finalTotal.getValue();
   }
}
```

As you can see I have an inner class Item that contains the data (the name and the sub-totals). I've added a listener to the `newItem.productTotalProperty()`, but this only seems to work when the new Item is constructed: when a product's field is changed, its instance's total is updated, but the binding to the Summary object stops working, so none of its fields are changed.

Here is the test driver code:

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class BindingsPrototypeTestDriver {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Product A = new Product("Pencil", 1.50f, 300);
      Product B = new Product("Eraser", 0.50f, 200);
      Product C = new Product("Paper", 4.95f, 100);
      ObservableList<Product> products = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
      products.add(A);
      products.add(B);
      products.add(C);
      Summary summary = new Summary();
      for(Product p: products)
      {
         Summary.Item summaryItem = summary.add();
         summaryItem.productNameProperty().bind(p.productNameProperty());
         summaryItem.productTotalProperty().bind(p.productTotalProperty());
      }
      
             for(Product p: products){ System.out.println(p.toString()); }
             System.out.println(summary.toString());
      C.setQuantity(200);
            for(Product p: products){ System.out.println(p.toString()); }
            System.out.println(summary.toString());
   }   
}
```

and here is the output:

```
run:
Item total changed from -1.0 to 450.0
Final total: FloatProperty [value: 450.0]
Item total changed from -1.0 to 100.0
Final total: FloatProperty [value: 550.0]
Item total changed from -1.0 to 494.99997
Final total: FloatProperty [value: 1045.0]
Product: Pencil, Price: 1.50, Quantity: 300, Total cost:  450.00
Product: Eraser, Price: 0.50, Quantity: 200, Total cost:  100.00
Product: Paper, Price: 4.95, Quantity: 100, Total cost:  495.00

Product: Pencil,  Product cost: 450.00
Product: Eraser,  Product cost: 100.00
Product: Paper,  Product cost: 495.00
Final total: 1045.0
Product: Pencil, Price: 1.50, Quantity: 300, Total cost:  450.00
Product: Eraser, Price: 0.50, Quantity: 200, Total cost:  100.00
Product: Paper, Price: 4.95, Quantity: 200, Total cost:  990.00

Product: Pencil,  Product cost: 450.00
Product: Eraser,  Product cost: 100.00
Product: Paper,  Product cost: 495.00
Final total: 1045.0
```

As you can see, when the "Paper" instance's quantity is changed to 200, everything updates correctly in the Product instance, but not in the Summary...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some issues.

The problem you encounter is that you use a property for `productTotal` that you don't update, but replace by a new property object every time the value updates. There's no way the user of your `Product` class could know about that. In fact the user expects the property getters to always return the same instance (and you did expect that too).

Instead of creating a new property, assign a new value to the old property, or just user the `Bindings` class for simplicity:

```
public class Product {
   private final StringProperty productName;
   private final FloatProperty priceEach;
   private final IntegerProperty quantity;
   private final FloatProperty productTotal;

   public Product(){
       this("Product Name", 0, 0);
   }

   public Product(String name, float priceEach, int quantity){
      this.productName = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
      this.priceEach = new SimpleFloatProperty(priceEach);
      this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
      this.productTotal = new SimpleFloatProperty();
      this.productTotal.bind(Bindings.multiply(this.quantity, this.priceEach));
   }

   public void setPriceEach(float price){
      priceEach.set(price);
   }

   ...
```

#### `Summary` class

- Why do add a nested `Item` class. You already have a `Product` class. Storing the data in memory twice doesn't make much sense. Also you rely on external code to bind the values for you... That's poor design.
- Even worse: your `itemsSummary` is `public` and non-`final` which means anyone with a reference to the `Summary` instance can change the value and the `Summary` instance isn't informed about that change. The only reason this isn't an issue here is that you don't make use of the list being an `ObservableList`. In fact you could replace all lists in the code with `ArrayList`s and it wouldn't make a difference.

Here's what I'd do:

- make `itemsSummary` `final` and maybe even `private` and provide a getter
- use a `ListChangeListener` to add / remove listers to / from the items of the list.
- Use a list of `Product`s

```
public class Summary {

    private final FloatProperty finalTotal;
    public final ObservableList<Product> itemsSummary;

    private final ChangeListener<Number> itemTotalChangeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        calculateTotal();
    };

    public Summary() {
        finalTotal = new SimpleFloatProperty(0);
        itemsSummary = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        itemsSummary.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Product> c) -> {
            boolean modified = false;
            while (c.next()) {
                if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    modified = true;
                    for (Product p : c.getRemoved()) {
                        p.productTotalProperty().removeListener(itemTotalChangeListener);
                    }
                }
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    modified = true;
                    for (Product p : c.getAddedSubList()) {
                        p.productTotalProperty().addListener(itemTotalChangeListener);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (modified) {
                calculateTotal();
            }
        });
    }

    ...
```

These modifications make the code in the `main` method a bit simpler:

```
    Product A = new Product("Pencil", 1.50f, 300);
    Product B = new Product("Eraser", 0.50f, 200);
    Product C = new Product("Paper", 4.95f, 100);

    // no need for a observable list here
    Product[] products = new Product[]{A, B, C};

    Summary summary = new Summary();
    summary.itemsSummary.setAll(products);

    for (Product p : products) {
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }
    ...
```

Comment: thanks fabian-- I think you've put me in the right direction. it's midnight where I am right now so I can't look at your code in detail until tomorrow, but just want to say the reason why I have the observable lists is to wire them up to dynamically updateable TableViews once I have an interface designed, a bit like the excel screen shot, so even though they don't have a function right now they will later on.